# if statement in php ( a little bit more complex )

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this issue, I want to have a dynamic if statement and it should state:

```
if (where!= value1 && where!= value2 && ... )
```

I am getting the values from an array and I am trying to do it by imploding it, something like this:

```
if (implode("$where!=" , $columns_array) { ... }
```

and as I imagined this doesn't work (I know why it doesn't work, that's just an example of what I am trying to do)

So anyone can give me an idea how do I do that, or is there a way to make something like

```
if ($where != (a list of values))
```

Does such syntax exist ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if (!in_array($where, $columns_array)) { /* do something */ }
```

The manual is your friend: [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array)